# Changing the lane of moving turtle on 3 lanes according to the color

Tags: simulation, netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I'm trying to extend the inbuilt model of NetLogo software, called Traffic 2 lanes, and modified little bit it as a bottle production line, which has three color bottles, moving in 3 lanes in random color order.

My requirement is, in original Traffic 2 lanes model, a car is changing the lane when it encounter a car which is going less speed than current one. My requirement is, the bottle (car) need change the lane if it encounters a different color bottle in the production line. Ultimately three lines have three different colours of the bottles. The line moves forward. (right direction).

Below is the code segment which is responsible to change the car lanes.

```
to move-to-target-lane ; turtle procedure
  set heading ifelse-value target-lane < ycor [ 180 ] [ 0 ]
  let blocking-cars other turtles in-cone (1 + abs (ycor - target-lane)) 180 with [ x-distance <= 1 ]
  let blocking-car min-one-of blocking-cars [ distance myself ]
  ifelse blocking-car = nobody [
    forward 0.2
    set ycor precision ycor 1 ; to avoid floating point errors
  ] [
    ; slow down if the car blocking us is behind, otherwise speed up
    ifelse towards blocking-car <= 180 [ slow-down-car ] [ speed-up-car ]
  ]
 end
```

Here is the link for the NetLogo project file. I have very little knowledge of NetLogo and appreciate your support to enhance my knowledge of NetLogo.

[Traffic lane simulation NetLogo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13llnPEmOUXtfzjIKWU7741w_crmGn4Yj/view?usp=drive_link)

Regards!

I tried similar examples from other libraries, and online examples, but always it getting errors. i want to help me someone on this.

Comment: It mostly looks to be working. In short order, all cars go the same speed and none have negative patience, so lane changing stops. If you set deceleration to its max and acceleration to its min, you'll see persistent lane changing.